# migrate failed i've changed the format and still failed

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

i'm Trying to migrate but it fails with this error and i've changed the format of the album_id/image_id to both integer and it keep giving this error

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `moses_photography`.`images` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `images` add constraint `images_album_id_foreign` foreign key (`album_id`) references `albums` (`image_id`))

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\moses_photography\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:716
    712▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    713▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    714▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    715▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 716▕             throw new QueryException(
    717▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    718▕             );
    719▕         }
    720▕     }

  1   C:\xampp\htdocs\moses_photography\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:501
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `moses_photography`.`images` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\moses_photography\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:501
      PDOStatement::execute()
```

albums table migration

```
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('albums', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('category_id');
            $table->integer('image_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

images table migration

```
        Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('album_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('album_id')->references('image_id')->on('albums');
            $table->string('filename');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: Are you running `albums` migration first? Also, you can do `$table->unsignedInteger('album_id');` or `$table->foreignId('album_id');`

Comment: like @matiaslauriti said My guess is that albums is not running first, you can change the timestamp on the migration so it sits above the album one if you want. otherwise you can disable key constraints until all have finished running.

Comment: 'image_id' is not primary  key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `SQL` the foreign key, needs to have the same type as the referenced id. Laravel migrations method `->id()`, is not an `unsignedInteger()` but an `unsignedBigInteger()`. So the following changes should help you.

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('album_id');
$table->foreign('album_id')->references('image_id')->on('albums');
```

Comment: had a small test project yesterday that had this exact same error :) remember to manually cleanup leftovers from migrations if you want to run it again.